Javascript - Trigger collision by dragging two objects together?
I am trying to make a div detect a collision with an img by touch dragging it next to the img which will trigger the prompt 'hello world'
<img id="ww" img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxeJcgT02m77yhBGI1zncC2Rk2lELwdHZPzUhBQiHeiw&s"</img><p>

<div id="kk" ></div>

<style>

#kk {width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#f00;position:absolute}

</style>

<script>



var draggable = document.getElementById('kk');

  draggable.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {

    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];

    

    // Place element where the finger is

    draggable.style.left = touch.pageX-25 + 'px';

    draggable.style.top = touch.pageY-25 + 'px';

    event.preventDefault();

  }, false);



var rect1 = document.getElementById("ww")

var rect2 = document.getElementById("kk")



if (rect1.x < rect2.x)

{

   prompt('Hello world')

}

</script>

It is not working. Is something wrong with the div or the img dragging together to form a collision? Any suggestions?
